# What happens to queued messages when Logback's AsyncAppender crashes?

Tags: java, logback, asyncappender

When using Logback's `AsyncAppender`, messages get queued before they
are written to their final destination (depending on which `Appender`
you wrapped with the `AsyncAppender`).  So far so good.

Is it possible those queued messages get lost when my program or logback itself crash?

Comment: grammar, formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think queued messages will be lost when JVM crashed and even normal program shutdown.

I was doing an investigation on how much time is improved when using `AsyncAppender`.

Sample **logback.xml**:
I have a normal FILE_LOG and ASYNC_FILE_LOG.

```
<appender name="FILE0" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./file.log</file>
    ... (not relevant)
</appender>

<appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./async_file.log</file>
    ... (not relevant)
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC_FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
</appender>

<logger name="FILE_LOG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE0" />
</logger>

<logger name="ASYNC_FILE_LOG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILE1" />
</logger>
```

Sample **MultiThreadsExecutor** tester program, it should generate 1010 lines of log messages:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MultiThreadsExecutor {
    private static final Logger asyncLOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ASYNC_FILE_LOG");
    private static final Logger normaLOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FILE_LOG");
    static CountDownLatch latch = null; // Java7 feature to ensure all threads ended execution.

    public MultiThreadsExecutor() {
    }

    public void someMethod(String who, String loggerName) {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getLogger(loggerName).warn(Thread.currentThread().getName() +": is Running in the background");
                for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                    getLogger(loggerName).info(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" counting: " + i);
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        },"Background " + who + " Thread");
        backgroundThread.start();
    }

    private Logger getLogger(String name) {
        if (name.equals("ASYNC_FILE_LOG")) {
            return asyncLOGGER;
        } else if (name.equals("FILE_LOG")) {
            return normaLOGGER;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Logger Undefined");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start;
        MultiThreadsExecutor mte = new MultiThreadsExecutor();

        latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            mte.someMethod(Integer.toString(i)," FILE_LOG");
        }
        try {
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("FILE_LOG ended - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            mte.someMethod(Integer.toString(i)," ASYNC_FILE_LOG");
        }
        try {
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("ASYNC_FILE_LOG ended - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Remove below to enable Testcase(2)
        // try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println("END");
   }
}
```

**Test Case (1) Normal execution.**

> FILE_LOG ended - 46
>   ASYNC_FILE_LOG ended - 16
>   END

ASYNC_FILE_LOG indeed is much faster. However...

File.log recorded 1010 line of messages correctly:

```
line1 Background 1 Thread: is Running in the background
line2 Background 3 Thread: is Running in the background
line3 Background 6 Thread: is Running in the background
line4 Background 8 Thread: is Running in the background
...
line1009 Background 0 Thread counting: 99
line1010 Background 8 Thread counting: 99
```

Async_File.log records up to 800+ messages only!

```
line1 Background 0 Thread: is Running in the background
line2 Background 1 Thread: is Running in the background
line3 Background 1 Thread counting: 0
line4 Background 1 Thread counting: 1
line5 Background 1 Thread counting: 2
....
line811 Background 2 Thread counting: 95
line812 Background 4 Thread counting: 66
line813 Background 8 Thread counting: 46
```

**Test Case (2) , Tester sleeps 1 second before END in case AsyncAppender needs time to clear queue...**

> FILE_LOG ended - 47
>   ASYNC_FILE_LOG ended - 16
>   END

ASYNC_FILE_LOG is still faster. This time, ASYNC_FILE_LOG recorded 1010 lines correctly.

```
line1 Background 0 Thread: is Running in the background
line2 Background 2 Thread: is Running in the background
line3 Background 2 Thread counting: 0
line4 Background 2 Thread counting: 1
line5 Background 2 Thread counting: 2
....
line1008 Background 5 Thread counting: 97
line1009 Background 5 Thread counting: 98
line1010 Background 5 Thread counting: 99
```

**Conclusion**

The above test proves that, when Java program shutdown, `AsyncAppender` does not have enough time to clear log queue. Not to mention JVM crashes, Java program exit is immediate.